# R - How to change stacked bar chart order for individual bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

For the following stacked bar chart I would like to change the order of the "fill" parts of each bar in the graph individually. For example, I want the green portion of the first bar to be on the bottom but I want the blue portion to be on the bottom for the second bar. Is this possible?

```
# library
library(ggplot2)

# create a dataset
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3) )
condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 4)
value <- abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
data <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)

# Stacked + percent
ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")
```

[Resulting Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjBGJ.png)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You need to arrange the values within each species from largest to smallest, and plot with species as a grouping variable:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data %>% group_by(specie) %>% arrange(-value, by_group = TRUE),
       aes(fill = condition, y = value, x = specie, group = specie)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect thank you! Though I am having an issue with the arrange function and get the following error:

Error: incorrect size (1) at position 2, expecting : 12

Comment: @braun_tube have you made sure you are specifying `dplyr::arrange`?